# How can I differ + and 4 virtual code in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I took input from keyboard.

I took like this:

```js
if (48 <= key && key <= 57) {
    var number = String.fromCharCode(key);
    takeNumber(number);
}
```

Number 4's virtual code is 52.
but + symbol's virtual number is also 52.
How can I differ + and 4?

Comment: Can you update the question to a runnable example demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode key code of `4` is 52 and of `+` is 187. To differentiate between them use `onkeypress` and `onkeydown` events.

**Note:
The `keydown` event occurs when the keyboard key is pressed, and it is followed at once by the execution of keypress event.**

In `javascript` you can differ between these two in this way:

```js
function uniCharCode(event) {
    var char = event.which || event.keyCode;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Unicode CHARACTER code: " + char;
}

function uniKeyCode(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Unicode KEY code: " + key;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="uniCharCode(event)" onkeydown="uniKeyCode(event)">

<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare using 'charCodeAt' or 'String.fromCharCode'

```
'+'.charCodeAt() // 43
'4'.charCodeAt() // 52
String.fromCharCode(43) // '+'
String.fromCharCode(52) // 4
```